# JupyterLab move all contents of collapsed cell group

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I just started using [collapsible_headings](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/collapsible_headings/readme.html) in Jupyter Lab, after some difficulty finding a version that didn't have [this problem](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1529).  The version I am using is:

```
jupyter-dash              0.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py37h06a4308_0  
jupyter_highlight_selected_word 0.2.0           py37h89c1867_1002    conda-forge
jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.6           pyhd8ed1ab_1002    conda-forge
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.4.1            py37h89c1867_2    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.4.1            py37h06a4308_0  
jupyterlab                3.0.16             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
nbclassic                 0.2.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_1  
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

I would like to be able to drag-and-drop whole collapsed section groups from one place to another.  For example, where Database is selected, to drag Database and everything inside it to below Diagram:

[image: Jupyter cells]

When I try this, it seems that only the *title* of the section gets moved, and the contents of the section stay put.

Is there a way to set this up so that I can move whole sections at once, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: This is work in progress and should be available in JupyterLab 3.1: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10571 (in core, no extension will be needed). I hope it will be included in next pre-release (which may be beta2 or rc0) - please do subscribe to that PR and help testing once available.